# Serious issue with Swipebox and Google Chrome mobile

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, touch, swipe

Good evening everyone, I have a serious issue with SWIPEBOX galleries and Google chrome mobile. 
Now please let me state that I am a total beginner in jquery and javascript and don't know what I am doing.

I am trying to create 5 separate galleries on the same page. I followed the vague steps on the swipebox website and gave each class its own unique name

class="swipebox1", class="swipebox2", class="swipebox3" (kept it simple).

```
eg.
<div class="box">
<a href="example/assets/full/leap.jpg" class="swipebox1" title="Leap">
<img src="example/assets/leap_thumb.jpg" alt="leap"></a>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a href="example/assets/full/leap.jpg" class="swipebox2" title="Leap">
<img src="example/assets/leap_thumb.jpg" alt="leap"></a>
</div>
```

The problem is that Google Chrome mobile only allows touch/tap on the buttons (close, next, previous) in the first gallery..  The second and third galleries, you can only swipe (none of the buttons work)... So you cant close... :(

I have tested this on all other browsers and it works fine (webkit mobile, dolphin mobile, safari pc, safari mac, IE10 pc, Opera pc, Nightly pc)... I have not made any changes to the swipebox css or js files... (wouldn't know what to change anyway)

Also, my script is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($) {
        $(".swipebox1").swipebox();
        $(".swipebox2").swipebox();
        $(".swipebox3").swipebox();
     });
    </script>
```

I hope this is right!!!

I also tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(function($) {
        $(".swipebox1, .swipebox2, .swipebox3").swipebox();
     });
 </script>
```

but that just added them together, which I didn't want...

I really need someone's help on this as I am almost finished with my responsive website and this is the only thing holding me back...

thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

Try to leave class as "swipebox", I mean like this:

```
class="swipebox"
```

everywhere for each of your 3 galleries.

To run Swipebox use "rel" attribute like this:

```
<div class="box">
<a rel="gallery-1" href="example/assets/full/leap.jpg" class="swipebox" title="Leap">
<img src="example/assets/leap_thumb.jpg" alt="leap"></a>
</div>

<div class="box">
<a rel="gallery-2" href="example/assets/full/leap.jpg" class="swipebox" title="Leap">
<img src="example/assets/leap_thumb.jpg" alt="leap"></a>
</div>
```

Let us know if that works!

Comment: Documentation of "rel" grouping: http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#advanced